# The most elegant way to walk trees in PHP

Tags: php, tree

I have trees like this one:

```
$tree = array("A", array(
            array("B", 1),
            array("C", 2),
            array("D",
                array("E",
                    array("F")),
                array("G")),
            array("H", 3)));
```

Each node is an array, type of node is its first element and other elements are node's arguments (they can be list of other nodes, single node, some value etc.; node can have no argument, one argument or more arguments).

What do you think is the most elegant way to walk these type of trees?

I came up with two possibilities:

1) using `switch` statement

```
/*
 * + shorter
 * + fall-througs (easy way to handle more nodes with same code)
 *
 * - worse readability
 */
function my_tree_walker($tree)
{
    switch ($tree[0]) {
        case 'A':
            list($_, $subnodes) = $tree;
            $ret = '';

            foreach ($subnodes as $subnode) {
                $ret .= my_tree_walker($subnode);
            }

            return $ret;

        break;
        case 'B': /*...*/ break;
        case 'C': /*...*/ break;
        case 'D': /*...*/ break;
        case 'E': /*...*/ break;
        case 'F': /*...*/ break;
        case 'G': /*...*/ break;
        case 'H': /*...*/ break;
    }
}
```

2) object with method for each node type

```
/*
 * + better readability
 * + more declarative
 *
 * - longer
 * - `new static` is PHP >=5.3 only
 */

abstract class TreeWalker
{
    protected function __construct(){}

    final protected function walk($node)
    {
        $nodetype = array_shift($node);
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'walk' . $nodetype), $node);
    }

    public static function w($tree)
    {
        $instance = new static;
        return $instance->walk($tree);
    }
}

final class MyTreeWalker extends TreeWalker
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        // initialize
    }

    private function walkA($subnodes)
    {
        $ret = '';

        foreach ($subnodes as $subnode) {
            $ret .= $this->walk($subnode);
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    private function walkB($n) { /*...*/ }
    private function walkC($n) { /*...*/ }
    private function walkD($subnode) { /*...*/ }
    private function walkE() { /*...*/ }
    private function walkF() { /*...*/ }
    private function walkG() { /*...*/ }
    private function walkH($n) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Or do you suggest even more elegant way of walking trees?

I also considered nodes being objects and instead of separate tree walkers each node would have methods for walks inside. However I think it will make code harder to maintain, because parts of walkers' code will be placed in different locations and it will be harder to use same code for more nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined both ways and created DSL:

```
A ($subnodes) {
    $ret = '';
    foreach ($subnodes as $subnode) {
        $ret .= WALK($subnode);
    }

    return $ret;
}
B ($n) { /*...*/ }
C ($n) { /*...*/ }
D ($subnode) { /*...*/ }
E () { /*...*/ }
F () { /*...*/ }
G () { /*...*/ }
H ($n) { /*...*/ }
```

that is translated to PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I think simplicity is elegant.

No need to reinvent the wheel! PHP comes equipped with [SPL (Standard PHP Library)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) which offers several [Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) that can do all the work for you.

A few to check out would be [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Comment: The problem is all nodes won't be processed the same. There will still be need for switch or something. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect to do with the nodes so we have a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to refactor tree walkers (like these: http://github.com/jakubkulhan/phpeg/blob/master/lib/phpgen.php#L506, http://github.com/jakubkulhan/phpeg/blob/master/lib/phpgen.php#L551, http://github.com/jakubkulhan/phpeg/blob/master/lib/phpgen.php#L195 and following methods that start with 'g') in my PEG generator . I want to make them separate (separate class/function) and to use same language constructs.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at:

- [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)
- [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Comment: The problem is all nodes won't be processed the same. There will still be need for switch or something. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jak The traversal itself is independent of what the data structures, as long as they're iterable. If you want to treat the elements differently, yes, you'll still need a switch statement or you can use objects instead of arrays and take advantage of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I considered objects and I think they would be more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library: https://packagist.org/packages/lukascivil/treewalker

TreeWalker is a simple and small Library that will help you to work faster with manipulation of structures in PHP

- getdiff() - Get json difference
- walker() - Edit json (Recursively)
- structMerge() - Joins two structures
- createDynamicallyObjects() - Create nested structure by Dynamic keys
- getDynamicallyValue() - Dynamically get a structure property
- setDynamicallyValue() - Dynamically access a structure property to set a value

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple recursive function that effectively walks a tree. Here it is

```
   function deep_cetegories($categories){
     foreach($categories as $category)
  {
    print_r((json_encode($category['category_name'])));
    if(isset($category['children']))
    {
        deep_cetegories($category['children']);
    }

  }
}
```